# What is the cause of the Bad Request Error when handling a form in flask?

Tags: python, flask, upload, bad-request

After reading many similar sounding problems and the relevant Flask docs, I cannot seem to figure out what is generating the following error upon submitting a form:

> 400 Bad Request
>
> The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not
>   understand.

```
@app.route('/uploadtodos', methods=['POST','GET'])
def uploadtodos():
    file= request.files['inputFile']

    newFile = FileContents(name=file.filename, data= file.read())
    db.session.add(newFile)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('uploadtodos.html') 



<form method="POST" action ="/uploadtodos" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <label for="inputFile"></label>
        <input type="file" name="inputFile">
        <!--input type="submit" -->
        <button type="submit">submit</button> 
    </form>
```

Comment: Is there any information in the flask development server's console?

Comment: You have a `form` making a POST request, but you have not specified it directly in your `uploadtodos` definition

Answer (score 0):

the hole probleme resumed just in one "if" that i forgot myself.

```
@app.route('/uploadtodos', methods=['POST','GET'])
    def uploadtodos():
        if request.method =='POST':
            file= request.files['inputFile']

            newFile = FileContents(name=file.filename,data=file.read())
            db.session.add(newFile)
            db.session.commit()
            return 'Saved ' +file.filename + ' to the database!'
      return render_template('uploadtodos.html')
```